# android:If not happen in 15 seconds do this condition

Tags: android, multithreading, message, one-time-password

I want to add a condition on OTP recieve app.In which if its not signing up automatically when message come after 15 seconds it should  allow the user to manually enter the OTP.I think there must be use of thread or handler?

Comment: or countdowntimer.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   private CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(15000, 1000 / 100) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long l) {
       // call when timer start
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Done",    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

to start Timer

```
countDownTimer.start()
```

Comment: actually i m doing this in otp verifier in which if its logging automatically it should not come to onfinish().How can I do that because after 15 seconds onfinish() is excecuting. i dont want that

Comment: i dont get ideat what u say 
to stop timer just do
countDownTimer.cancel();

Comment: @TouseefAhmed if my answer help you than accept my answer