# After few min return to login screen in android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm creating one small app login screen and registration screen and four other screen.I stored data in SharedPreference.If the user accessing the app after 20 min it have to automatically redirect to login screen.I have little knowledge about CountDownTimer ,But i don't know how to use it here.Help to solve my issue.

Comment: store the time stamp of the last login in shared preferences and check for 20 min expiration each time the app is opened either in applicationloader or in your launcher activity.

Comment: Any special need for CountDownTimer? You could save the time when user logged in to SharedPreferences and then when the user re-opens the app, just check if the last saved time was 20 minutes ago. If so, delete saved credentials and ask to log-in again.

Comment: No i don't have any idea about timer in android. I used only CountDownTimer that's why i mentioned.

Comment: If the user dint use the app  20 min how to redirect to login screen please show some code.It will give some idea.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36622494/6067866

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the time of last login to your shared preferences and update the value on successful login. Check for expiration each time the app is opened.

MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    int timeOfLastLogin = getPreferenceInt("last_login");
    if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timeOfLastLogin > 1000*60*20){
        Intent loginIntent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(loginIntent);
        finish();
    }
}

//...

}
```

Login Activity :

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

//...
    public void login(){
        // Your login logic
        setPreferenceInt("last_login", System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your code.It gave clear idea and i will try this code.

Comment: In this case, if user logged in and accessing app for 20 minutes and then quits the app, then it will again prompt for alert even after a minute,according to question after user quits it need to count 20.

Answer (score 1):

In that case.

While user quits the app from `Activity`, in `ondestroy()` method save the current time when user quits the app.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
   editor.put("lastLoggedIn",calendar.getTime().getTime());
   editor.commit();
   super.onDestroy();
}
```

When user log's in Again,check for difference in time in `onCreate()`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle instance){
...
 long oldTime = pref.getLong(this,"lastLoggedIn",0);
  if(oldTime != 0){
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    long currentTime = cal.getTime().getTime();
    long diff = currentTime - oldTime;
    long diffSec = diff / 1000;
    long min = diffSec / 60;
     if(min > 20){
        //alert 
     }
  }

...
}
```

Comment: I think the requirement is to prompt to login again if the user opens the app after 20 minutes. This solution is correct if the user is to be explicitly logged out in 20 minutes even when the session is open.

Comment: According to official android references, `Note: do not count on this method being called as a place for saving data! For example, if an activity is editing data in a content provider, those edits should be committed in either onPause() or onSaveInstanceState(Bundle), not here.` So save it in onStop().